# How to relate 2 user profile tables to a single login table?

Tags: mysql

I have an **Employee** table , and another table named **Student**. Now I have a third table named the **Login**. 
**Employee** has emp_id as PK , and other specific attributes for an employee.
**Student** has std_id as PK , and other specific attributes for a student.

The **login** table has user_id as PK , but the user_id should also be FK from both employee and student. Means that if there is a profile for an Employee or Student then there will be a record for them in the login table. But I am not able to link the user_id of the **Login** table to both Employee and Student at the same time in a **one-to-one** relationship.

Could you please help me how to that. I am using **MySQL** for this.

Answer (score 1):

A **Login** maybe a **Student** or an **Employee**.

It sounds like you trying to define a FK relationship from **Login** to both **Student** and **Employee**, this is not correct.  You should be defining a FK relationship from **Student** to **Login** and **Employee** to **Login**

**Edit for clarification:**

If the PK emp_id for **Employee** and PK std_id for **Student** are the FK field then there can only be 1 for each given **Login** (user_id value).

Comment: That way a login would be related to many students and many employees. I think he wants the opposite.

Comment: No not necessarily.  If the PK emp_id for **Employee** and PK std_id for **Student** are the FK field then there can only be 1 for each given **Login** (user_id value).

Comment: Well, state that in your answer!

Comment: I thought that it was implicit in the question.  However as you suggested I have explicitly stated it in the answer.